# What's the cost of conversion from std::unique_ptr<Dervied> to std::unique_ptr<Base>?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider a simple piece of code:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

std::unique_ptr<Base> foo()
{
    return std::make_unique<Derived>();
}
```

I know `std::unique_ptr` manages conversion for related types well, similarly to inheritance. However, is this true that `std::unique_ptr<Base>` and `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` are in fact unrelated, and the provided code is possible (and works) thanks to conversions rather than inheritance?

If that is the case, this conversion must come with a cost. I'd assume conversion from `Derived&` to `Base&` to be for free.  Is this `std::unique_ptr` costing me much?

---

Note: The question is based on presumption that there exists a function:

- that is called a lot,
- can be implemented via above conversion, or in a dirtier way: `return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived());`,
- performance is king.

Comment: There are user-defined conversions that make this code Work As Expected. The power of C++ is that it allows you write library components like this that feel natural, and you can do that entirely within the language itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion should be essentially free; `std::unique_ptr` is just a wrapper around a pointer, and the "conversion" between the pointers stored in `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` and `std::unique_ptr<Base>` is purely formal (i.e. it happens just in the type system), the actual value is untouched.

This can be easily seen [in the generated code](https://godbolt.org/g/4YSCPl), which boils down to copying the pointer and the deleter into the new `std::unique_ptr` and zeroing out the pointer in the old one.

Comment: Nice site, need to remember that. Good to know the exact cost, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> What's the cost of conversion from `std::unique_ptr<Dervied>` to `std::unique_ptr<Base>`?
>
> I'd assume conversion from `Derived&` to `Base&` to be for free. Is this `std::unique_ptr` costing me much?

Depends on the optimisation levels being applied. But from the OP, you probably have those turned on, so essentially nothing. The pointer conversion is very cheap.

To truly evaluate what the cost is, the binary will need to be checked. [See here](https://godbolt.org/g/4E2TDZ) for a sample of this output;

```
foo():                                # @foo()
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    %rdi, %rbx
        movl    $1, %edi
        callq   operator new(unsigned long)
        movq    %rax, (%rbx)
        movq    %rbx, %rax
        popq    %rbx
        retq
```